# Проблема при разворачивании битрикса

Tags: php, битрикс

Сайт работал в кодировке UTF-8. Конфигурация сервера не соответствует требованиям.
Для продолжения установите настройки PHP: mbstring.func_overload=2 и mbstring.internal_encoding=UTF-8.

Как исправить данную ситуацию? Сервер боевой.

Comment: исправьте настройки php в файле php.ini или в веб интерфейсе хостинга/сервера, смотря на какой сервер/хостинг разворачиваете

Comment: каким образом можно исправить php.ini для решения проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Если нет доступа к php.ini, то в корне сайта есть файл .htaccess, в нем, в блоке 
`<IfModule mod_php...`
добавляете

```
php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
```

Comment: не помогает данная вставка

Answer (score 1):

В предыдущем ответе все верно сказано, то есть, нужно в `.htaccess` добавить:

```
php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
```

только вот на счет `<IfModule mod_php...` не совсем ясно, смотрите, если у вас php 7 версии, то вот эта конструкция должна выглядеть так:

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
   php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
   php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>
```

если PHP 5 версии, то:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
   php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно проблема и остановка восстановления возникает перед восстановлением базы данных. Если именно такая ошибка прерывает восстановление, то это значит, что файлы восстановлены, а база нет. Восстановите базу данных вручную другими средствами, например через экспорт/импорт phpMyAdmin.

В файлах восстановленной копии

```
/bitrix/.settings.php и 
/bitrix/php_interface/dbconn.php
```

пропишите имя базы и логин/пароль к базе данных.

Сайт будет работать, правда глючить будет в разных местах непредвиденно, поэтому потом нужно все же выполнить рекомендации, написанные ранее.

Answer (score 0):

Открываем:

```
/etc/php.d/bitrixenv.ini
```

Ищем строку:

```
; Utf-8 support
default_charset = UTF-8
```

Заменяем на:

```
; Utf-8 support
default_charset = UTF-8
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
mbstring.func_overload = 2
```

Перезагружаем Apache:

```
apachectl restart
```